# Working with bits using and,or..etc operations

Tags: c, bit

Write a C program that reads from the keyboard two numbers a and b
(0 <= a, b <16) and displays the values obtained by applying to a and b a
operators and logic, or logic, and bit, or bit, or exclusively bitwise.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b;

    printf("Introduceti primul numar :\n"); scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Introduceti al doilea numar :\n"); scanf("%d",&b);

    printf("\nAplicarea asupra lui a si be a operatorilor:\n");
    printf("Si logic = %d\n",a&b); //or 
    printf("Sau logic = %d\n",a|b); //and
    printf("Si pe biti = %d\n",); //bit or  
    printf("Sau pe biti = %d\n",); //bit and
    printf("Sau exclusiv pe biti = %d\n",); //exclusive bit or
}
```

I have trouble with the bit part.

Comment: You mix AND and OR. And the *logic* operators are `&&` and `||`. I suggest you spend more time with your books or class-notes, as they should already contain all this information.

Comment: And a hint about presenting bitwise operations: Print using hexadecimal (`"%x"`) as it's then easier to calculate which bits are set or not.

Answer (score 0):

The operators `&` (bit-wise **AND**), `|` (bit-wise **OR**) you used are the actual bit-wise operators. The logic operators are denoted `&&`, `||`:

```
printf("Si logic = %d\n",a || b); //or 
printf("Sau logic = %d\n",a && b); //and
printf("Si pe biti = %d\n", a | b); //bit or  
printf("Sau pe biti = %d\n", a & b); //bit and
printf("Sau exclusiv pe biti = %d\n", a ^ b); //exclusive bit or
```

You can print the output in the hexadecimal base to understand how the bit-wise operators calculated their output:

```
printf("Si pe biti = %x\n", a | b); //bit or  
printf("Sau pe biti = %x\n", a & b); //bit and
printf("Sau exclusiv pe biti = %x\n", a ^ b); //exclusive bit or
```